# Calculating the SD of averaged data, based on descriptive statistics of the contributing conditions

Tags: standard-deviation, mean

I am conducting a meta analysis and wish to calculate the standard deviation (SD) of the *average* of 3 conditions.

By this, I mean the SD of the vector (conditionav) that summarises the data from the 3 conditions that contribute to this average: conditionav=(condition1+condition2+condition3)/3

However, the only data I have available are the descriptive statistics of the 3 contributing conditions that I wish to average (i.e. the Ms and SDs of condition1, condition2, condition3).

Therefore to estimate the SD of conditionav, I have taken the mean of the SDs of the contributing conditions (condition1, conditon2, condition3). However, this seems to always lead to over-estimations of the SD of conditionav.

I was wondering if there is some way of calculating the SD of the average data, based on the descriptive statistics of the contributing conditions.

Please see the code below for the problem illustrated in R terms.

Thanks for any help!

```
# We want to calculate the standard deviation of the average of 3 conditions (SDAV) based
# on the standard deviations of the 3 contributing conditions.

# Set seed
set.seed(1)

# Create 3 conditions
condition1=rnorm(20,10,10)
condition2=rnorm(20,5,3)
condition3=rnorm(20,2,5)

# Now create a vector that represents the average of the 3 conditions.
conditionav=(condition1+condition2+condition3)/3

# Take the SD of the average data. This is the value we want to calculate.
SDAV=sd(conditionav)

# However, only the descriptive statistics of the contributing conditions are reported, 
# so we just take the average of these as an estimate of the SD of the average data.
estimate=(sd(condition1)+sd(condition2)+sd(condition3))/3


# As you can see, our estimate is not the same thing as the standard deviation of the 
# average data, since our estimate is 5.27 and the value we are trying to get is 3.53.
print(estimate)
print(SDAV)
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining standard deviations is a little bit more tricky than combining means. Just have a look at the Cochrane Handbook (http://handbook.cochrane.org/chapter_7/7_7_3_8_combining_groups.htm), they give the formula for two groups, but you'll get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response. As the equation for N in the Cochrane handbook is N1 + N2, I suspect the SD equation is for concatenating the groups. However, I am looking for the SD of the average group (conditionav in the R code, where N is the same). The contributing conditions are within-subjects rather than independent groups of observers - as such, concatenating the observations is clearly not the right thing to do.